# PySpark - why does my query time out when joining two previously cached dfs?

Tags: apache-spark, caching, pyspark

I have a query, which scans a huge table and I store the results in data_df.

From this, I create two data frames:

- df_pivot - I group data_df by one column, and pivot on another - a hefty operation
- df_sum - I group data_df by the same column, and just count, no pivot this time

I cache at each of these three steps - data_df, df_pivot, df_sum.

Then I simply join df_pivot onto df_sum. I see "Running command" until the timeout error `TimeoutException: Futures timed out after [300 seconds]` appears.

OK, nothing *too* weird so far. Since caching is lazy, all this is happening at once, it's a lot of work, and it times out.

But here's what's weird. If I `display` data_df, df_pivot, and df_sum, I still get the error.

Why? I have now activated the caching with `display` - so the big parts of the operation should be done, right?

df_pivot and df_sum are less than 100 rows each. So once they are cached, the join that's happening is very simple.

I'm able to get around the error with:

`spark.conf.set("spark.sql.autoBroadcastJoinThreshold", 900)`

But I'm just wondering why it still happens, when the heavy lifting has already been done and cached.

I checked the Spark UI, and there is plenty of space available in memory. Any thoughts?